# how to share live location details on sms for tracking From MAUI?

Tags: .net, maui, visual-studio-2022

how to share live location details on sms for tracking From MAUI?

when i open a page in maui app
the device share a google map live location to another user via sms

by using that link, user able to track the first user via google map

code for above solution?

Comment: Do you know how to get the current location?  Do you know how to send an SMS?  Both of these operations are well documented

Comment: i know how to get the current location and how to send an SMS. my need is to create a live tracking link of an object. is it possible using maui?

Comment: Your app would have to continuously broadcast its location to a server